# Viewing item details of a list in a new page with custom formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, custom-list

This may be a noob question, but my search didn't yield to anything, apologies first.

I am on Sharepoint Online and I would like to be able to click on an item (a row) in a SharePoint list and would like to see the details (all fields) in a new page, instead of the sidebar, and with my custom JSON formatting if possible, like showing Bing Maps instead of a text address, also with a custom layout like having two fields in one row.

I tried switching to Classic Experience from New Experience and other stuff in the List Settings, but nothing seemed to work.

Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In modern experience, the default list form is like you said, a sidebar on left hand. If you have access to PowerApps or InfoPath, you can create a custom list form for that list and when you open an item, the page shall be redirected to the new custom form.

And per my knowledge, in Classic experience, opening an Item shall redirect the current page to a page of item detailed information. What trouble did you meet?

By default, following the tutorial to [Switch the default experience for lists or document libraries from new or classic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-the-default-experience-for-lists-or-document-libraries-from-new-or-classic-66dac24b-4177-4775-bf50-3d267318caa9) shall help you. Please let me know if any issues occurs during this process.